# login page not redirecting to main page in iis server asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

Here is the c# coding using for `login` and `main` page redirection:

```
try
{
    db = new DBFunctions();
    string mSQL = ("SELECT COUNT(username) FROM [User] WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(username))='" + (txtusername.Text) + "'");
    db.Initialize("Text", mSQL);
    int mcount = Convert.ToInt32(db.cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    if (mcount == 1)
    {
        string mSQL1 = ("SELECT COUNT(username) FROM [User] WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(username))='" + (txtusername.Text) + "'");
        db.Initialize("Text", mSQL);
        int mcount1 = Convert.ToInt32(db.cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if (mcount1 == 1)
        {
            Response.Redirect("dash.aspx", false);
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Password Wrong.! Please Contact IT (377)')", true);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Username and Password does not match Please Contact IT (377)')", true);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Response.Write("<script>alert('"+ex.Message+"');</script>");
}
```

This above code works fine in `localhost environment` but if `host in iis server` it is not redirect to main page (if i click login button it just stay on `login page`).

Comment: Have you ever debug your code the other host and check what `mcount1` returns exactly?

Comment: Do you get any alerts on the page? If not, then your code is throwing an exception that you should log and analyse.

Comment: @SonerGönül mcount1 returns 1.

Comment: @nimeshjm i debugged code it works fine but not in server

Comment: @BalaManikandan Did you debug it on the server?

Comment: I wonder why you must call this code twice `("SELECT COUNT(username) FROM [User] WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(username))='" + (txtusername.Text) + "'")` Is it necessary to check this code twice? + Can you check your connection to Production database and do select with query above and see what count it will be.

Comment: @nimeshjm sorry i didn't, pls let me know server debug.

Comment: @BalaManikandan you can follow this article on how to do it: http://www.itworld.com/article/2699037/development/how-to-set-up-remote-debugging-in-visual-studio-2013.html It is a bit overkill for this case but is a good reference for the future. For now, you can log any errors when you catch the exception to a file and examine it.

Comment: 1) Are the dash.aspx in same folder? 2)did you checked if the permissions/authorization for the folder are ok? 3) have you tried to refer the root path in your url, like this Response.Redirect("~/dash.aspx"), or Response.Redirect("../dash.aspx") ?

Answer (score 1):

Localhost is not a server so in this case there might be a lot of reason to not work that your code. I think you are getting an exception and you are not catching it. I'll suggest to uncomment your code in  catching exception and see that.

Answer (score 0):

You May need to install/setup httpRedirect.

Kindly go through the below link for the more information.

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect

I hope it should work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i used the following line in web.config file

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\username" password="password"/>
```

this solved my problem.